# SSRS expression for variance %

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have two "Total" columns across two tablix as below:

one is SUM(Previous) and  the other is SUM(Current)

i'm trying to calculate Variance between these columns as "Expressions" in a new Tablix, I'm trying to get the PreviousTotal and CurrentTotal through SQL and then to calculate Variance as an expression.

how to calcualte variance in ssrs expression between these two columns ?

Comment: What do you mean by "variance between these columns"?

Comment: i'm trying to calculate variance % between  SUM(PreviousTotal)  and SUM(CurrentTotal) columns

Comment: i'm trying to calculate variance % between  SUM(Previous)  and SUM(Current) columns

Comment: what do you mean by 'tablix'?

Comment: @ivric . . . "variance" is a statistical measure, usually applied to a single variable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).  Sample data and desired results can usually really help a question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mean the variance, I think you mean something like "percentage deviation" from a *previous* to the *current* value. Why would you want to do this with a `SUM`? The difference between a "current sum" and a "previous sum" usually is just a "current value", and if you set this in relation to a 'SUM', it might look very small. But ok, in some scenarios this might make sense.

So, If you really want to calculate the "percentage deviation" of `SUM(Previous)` and `SUM(Current)`, the formula would be:

```
(SUM(Current) - SUM(Previous)) / SUM(Previous)
```

Format the value as a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Reference the `PreviousTotal` and `CurrentTotal` by Textbox ID.Value, and do math on them.

Comment: I'm not sure how to calculate the variance formula

Comment: currently i'm doing SUM(CurrentTotal )-SUM(PreviousTotal)

Comment: Then I don't understand what you're not sure of.